# Transit visa on arriving for Japan

Tags: visas, transit, japan, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival

I and my wife are visiting Sfo, USA on Indian passport and will be going back to Delhi via Tokyo, Japan by Ana airline in October. I want to see Tokyo, how to get the required transit visa on arrival?

Answer (score 2):

Japan never grants visas on arrival, only landing permissions, which are not visas. You may be referring to the landing permission provided by Article 15 of the [ICRRA](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/newimmiact/pdf/RefugeeRecognitionAct01.pdf), especially clause (2), which states

> (2) An immigration inspector may, upon application by the captain of the vessel or aircraft or the carrier who operates the vessel or aircraft, grant a foreign national (except for crew members) aboard the vessel or aircraft permission for landing in transit when such foreign national wishes to proceed via Japan to an area
>   outside Japan and to depart from Japan within 3 days of his/her entry into Japan from another port of entry or departure in the vicinity of the port at which the said foreign national entered Japan on board a vessel or aircraft other than
>   the one on which the foreign national arrived in Japan.

So it seems the airline must make an application on your behalf, and you should probably contact them.